# How to compute maximum pixel value of Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

This should be obvious, I thought. But I can't find easy way to find maximum among all pixels in a Mat of OpenCV. Of course, I can do following for each pixel type. But general max function would be still useful.

```
double cvMax(cv::Mat& mat)
{
float max=0;
float* pData=(float*)mat.data;
for(int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++) 
{
    for(int j=0;j<mat.cols;j++)
    {
        float value = pData[j+i*mat.cols];
        if(value>max) 
        {
            max=value;
        }
    }
}
return max;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could always use the std [max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) function with iterators from opencv

```
std::max_element(Mat.begin<double>(),Mat.end<double>());
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that max_element returns an iterator.

Comment: One note: I expect the Mat iterator to be pretty slow, as at each increment it has to check if you reached the end of a row (Matrix might be discontinuous, and there might be also padding bytes)

Answer (score 22):

[`cv::minMaxIdx`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxidx) is really simple to use. It looks complicated in the docs, but you can omit most of the parameters:

```
Mat m = ...;

double min, max;
minMaxIdx(m, &min, &max);

printf("min: %f, max: %f\n", min, max);
```

Moreover, `cv::minMaxIdx` is more than 10 times faster than `std::max_element`. This is because `cv::minMaxIdx` is optimized for handling `cv::Mat` data and it uses multiple threads if possible.

If you also need the locations of the minimum and maximum in the image, you can use [`cv::minMaxLoc`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc).

Comment: This is my preferred, as it allows use of more efficient lower-level code, vs generic iterators.

Answer (score 9):

There is also cv::minMaxLoc build-in function you could use. std::max_element is simpler in your case though.