# Find maximum value of a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, iterator, computer-vision

I am trying to find the maximum pixel value of a `cv::Mat`.

The Problem : `*maxValue` is always returning `0`.

From [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158756/using-stdmax-element-on-a-vectordouble), I understand that '`max_element` return iterators, not values. This is why I use `*maxValue`'

```
cv::Mat imageMatrix;

double  sigmaX = 0.0;
int ddepth = CV_16S; //  ddepth – The desired depth of the destination image


cv::GaussianBlur( [self cvMatFromUIImage:imageToProcess], imageMatrix, cv::Size(3,3), sigmaX);

cv::Laplacian(imageMatrix, imageMatrix, ddepth, 1);

std::max_element(imageMatrix.begin(),imageMatrix.end());

std::cout << "The maximum value is : " << *maxValue << std::endl;
```

Note : If `min_element` is substituted in place of `max_element`, and `minValue` in place of `maxValue`, `*minValue` will always return `0`.

Comment: Maybe imageMatrix is all zeros? Try printing it to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks stardust_. I printed it out to the console and it is not.

Comment: When I attempted to use `std::max_element(imageMatrix.begin(),imageMatrix.end());` I received the error `No matching member function call to begin`. I do not fully understand the `<typename_tp>`.

Comment: Ya I see man I thought it was a normal container. I think OpenCV has it's own containers. Maybe that's why std::max_element doesn't work on them.

Comment: What elements does imageMatrix contains?

Comment: You could use the minMaxLoc openCV function. [link]http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#void%20minMaxLoc%28InputArray%20src,%20double*%20minVal,%20double*%20maxVal,%20Point*%20minLoc,%20Point*%20maxLoc,%20InputArray%20mask%29[/link]

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-minmaxloc

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-reduce

Comment: Updated to show full code @shivakumar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find max and min lightness values of an image in opencv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724047/how-to-find-max-and-min-lightness-values-of-an-image-in-opencv)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should use the OpenCV built-in function `minMaxLoc` instead of `std` function.

```
Mat m;
//Initialize m
double minVal; 
double maxVal; 
Point minLoc; 
Point maxLoc;

minMaxLoc( m, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc );

cout << "min val: " << minVal << endl;
cout << "max val: " << maxVal << endl;
```

Comment: Cheers @shivakumar! I used `double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    
    cv::minMaxLoc(imageMatrix, &minVal, &maxVal);`

Comment: minMaxLoc is quite a slow function if what you are looking for is just the maximum value in the image... It's a problem difficult to avoid when using wider purpose functions.

Comment: @Antonio This answer tells minMaxLoc is super fast- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409969/1180117

Comment: @Kiran OP is apparently not interested in knowing the *location* of the max, but just the value. Now, you can use `minMaxIdx` which is the one actually mentioned to be fast (I suggest you update your answer). However, if you could have the same function to compute just the maximum, you would have half of the processing going on (not half of the memory reading though). If you have a very specific problem and you use a wider scope library function, you'll end up with some unnecessary computation, that's a general rule.

Comment: @Ríomhaire The reason why your initial code does not work is visible in [the link posted above by Kiran](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12521957/2436175): you would need to call `std::max_element(imageMatrix.begin<int16_t>(),imageMatrix.end<int16_t>());`. However, stay with shivakumar solution, which is more efficient

Comment: @Antonio It was not my answer. I was just referring to some body else answer.

Comment: @Kiran There is no misunderstanding. You should prefer `minMaxIdx` to `minMaxLoc` when you are not interested in the position of min and max, and therefore update your answer.

Comment: @Antonio Thanks. I got the point on `minMaxIdx` vs `minMaxLoc`. But, I am missing the part where you are referring to `my` answer. Which answer of mine are you referring to ?

Comment: @Kiran Ah, gosh, you are right! :) I thought you had answer here :) :)

Comment: @Antonio Ok. Also I am not in favour of `std::max_element`. I think it will fail if `Mat` is not continuous.

Comment: @Kiran Probably in the end not (I changed my opinion in the meantime :) ). I suppose the iterator is implemented in a way that checks if it reached the end of a row. I expect it just to be inefficient, but not wrong.

Comment: It seems to be okay only to one channel `cv::Mat`