# How to generally determine the best place (background) to put text in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-masking

[ORIGINAL PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwL3C.jpg)

[Masked photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkXjM.png)

After masking the original image, I have a black masked area on upper side of my image. Now I want to implement rectangle boundaries and implement the text into the center point of the rectangle. Then I can take something like that.

[This is what I expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMnKR.png)

```
def process(img):
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 50)
img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=1)
img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=1)
return img_erode
def get_masked(img):
h, w, _ = img.shape
center = h // 2, w // 2
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, center, False) > 0:
            mask = np.zeros((h, w), 'uint8')
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255, -1)
            return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

Now I have this code for getting black area, what should I do for the next step?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point of the masking.  If the second image is your goal, why not just put text on the raw image?

Comment: actually ı was trying to mask unused areas as you can the upper part of the photo is more suitable for placing text.my problem is not being able to identify areas inside the masked region

Comment: Is the second image your goal?  If not could you use Photoshop or paint to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes 2nd image is my goal. ı want to implement my text into image but this area must be the unused ı mean the outside of the object.

Comment: Answer updated with code, lmk if it gives you trouble.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually its not. so he solved my problem already :) thank you sneaky polar bear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Run a [distance transform](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_distance_transformation.htm) on your black area mask.  Take the highest value from that distance transform and use that location as the center of your text.  (you will want to make sure to put an edge around the image so that the distance transform pushes away from the boundaries of the image as well).  What this will do is find the black area furthest away from any non-background pixels.  You can use [minMaxLoc opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955305/find-maximum-value-of-a-cvmat) function to find the location of the highest value after the distance transform.

This will put the text anywhere on the picture (purely based on your background mask / image edges).  If you want to enforce some kind of limits (like background but only top left of screen, etc), just modify your mask accordingly (add in arbitrary positive edge pixels or shapes) before inverting and running the distance transform.

Some liberties that I took with your code:  I ran a canny right on the color image because it had better contrast properties than the grayscale as far as the sky is concerned.  I got rid of your closing morphology... I kinda understand why you wanted to do that to close shapes, but since I was doing a distance transform this step is unnecessary.

One additional step that could be implemented depending on your application is that you can keep the value of the max point as well as the location (make sure not to normalize) and if that value is less than half the max dimension of your text (probably width), then the text will clip into objects and/or the image edge which you may want to throw an error on (or change text size or something).

Here is the demonstration code that produced the images above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool debugFlag = true;
    std::string path = "C:/Local Software/voyDICOM/resources/images/cowboyPic.jpg";

    Mat originalImg = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (debugFlag) { imshow("orignal", originalImg); }

    Mat edged;
    cv::Canny(originalImg, edged, 150, 200); //canny runs just fine on color images (often better than grayscale depending)
    if (debugFlag) { imshow("edges", edged); }

    //set boundary pixels so text doesnt clip into image edge
    cv::rectangle(edged, Point(0,0), Point(edged.cols-1,edged.rows-1), 255,1);
    imshow("edges with boundary", edged);

    Mat inverted;//needs to be inverted for distance transform to work propperly
    bitwise_not(edged, inverted);

    Mat distMap;
    cv::distanceTransform(inverted, distMap, DIST_L1,3);
    if (debugFlag) 
    {
        //note that this normalization will limit your ability to enforce a fail case (if there is not sufficient room at best point)
        normalize(distMap, distMap, 0, 1.0, NORM_MINMAX); //this is only neccesary for visualization
        imshow("dist transform", distMap);
    }
    

    Point maxPt, minPt;
    double maxVal, minVal;
    minMaxLoc(distMap, &minVal, &maxVal, &minPt, &maxPt);

    //Estimate the size of the box so that you can offset the textbox from center point to top left corner.
    double fontScale = 1;
    int fontThick = 2;
    std::string sampleText = "TEST AREA";
    int baseline = 0;
    Size textSize = getTextSize(sampleText, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, fontScale, fontThick, &baseline);

    maxPt.x -= textSize.width/2;
    maxPt.y -= textSize.height/2;

    cv::putText(originalImg, "TEST AREA", maxPt, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, fontScale, Scalar(0, 0, 0), fontThick);
    imshow("Final", originalImg);
    
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your comment sir. I added the photo as "original photo" if you can try it will be great for me.

Comment: Did you give it a go?  distance transform is a pretty powerful tool that is a good one to get comfortable with

Comment: I'll give it a crack this afternoon.

Comment: sry bout c++, one of these days I will set up opencv with python on my laptop.

Comment: idk, not really the spirit of stack overflow tbh.  I gave you an answer using the library that you are using, the amount of effort to translate this back to python is not high.  You shouldn't expect copy paste answers on SO.